# Select field based on value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, case

There is mysql table `foo`:

```
a | b | c
----------
1 | 2 | 0
2 | 3 | 1
3 | 4 | 0
```

and a query

```sql
SELECT a-b as subA, b-a as subB FROM foo;

subA | subB
-----------
 -1  |   1
 -1  |   1
 -1  |   1
```

How can I select `a-b as sum` if c = 0 and `b-a as sum` if c = 1, so that I have this result:

```
sum
---
-1
 1
-1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression:

```
select f.*,
    case c 
        when 0 then a - b 
        when 1 then b - a
    end as res
from foo f
```

If `c` is always `0` or `1`, we can get a little fancy with `sign()`:

```
select f.*, sign(c - 0.5) * (b - a) as res 
from foo f
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT (a-b)*(1-2*c) AS `sum`
FROM foo
```

Comment: Great math. I like it!

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simple (look in [SQLize.online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=c93583f269479e2cc318dc2c26b11bf2&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80)):

```
SELECT 
    a-b as subA, 
    b-a as subB,
    CASE 
        WHEN c = 0 THEN a-b
        WHEN c = 1 THEN b-a
    END as sum
FROM foo;
```

Result:

```
+======+======+=====+
| subA | subB | sum |
+======+======+=====+
| -1   | 1    | -1  |
+------+------+-----+
| -1   | 1    | 1   |
+------+------+-----+
| -1   | 1    | -1  |
+------+------+-----+
```